# Hosting a custom application integrated with MS CRM dynamis online onto Windows Azure using CRM SDKs and web services

Tags: web-services, azure, assemblies, wif, dynamics-crm-online

I developed a Custom application that is able to consume the CRM Web services and perform Windows Live Id authentication, create, read and update operation in the CRM from the custom .NET page. It runs absolutely fine when I debug the application in Visual Studio 2010 but when I deploy the same application and try to authenticate it shows the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I am unable to understand where the issue has occured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the **Microsoft.IdentityModel** isn't installed on your instance. You'll need to install the assembly by using a startup task.

Follow this guide to install the WIF Runtime (contains Microsoft.IdentityModel): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sriharsha/archive/2012/04/07/windows-azure-unable-to-find-assembly-microsoft-identitymodel.aspx